# JsonSerializer writing fields as attributes

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

How can we write fields of object as attributes instead of elements within a custom JsonSerializer ?

I would like to avoid to write xml like this :

```
<object>
    <attribute1>value1</attribute1>
    <attribute2>value2</attribute2>
<object>
```

but like this :

```
<object attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" />
```